Connecting nodejs app to a mysql database using docker and docker-compose
I'm trying to connect my node.js app with a mysql database
This is my dockerfile
FROM node:latest  
WORKDIR /app 
COPY . /app 
RUN npm update 
RUN npm install 
RUN npm rebuild bcrypt 
ENV SERVER_PORT 3000 
EXPOSE $SERVER_PORT 
CMD ["npm", "start"]

This is myd docker-compose file
 services:
mysqldb:
image: mysql:8.0
container_name: mysqlcontainer
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
restart: unless-stopped
volumes:

- ./dbinit/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/0_init.sql

- $HOME/database:/var/lib/mysql
  ports:

- 3306:3306
  expose:

- 3306
  environment:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: hotel_managment
  MYSQL_USER: admin
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: letmein
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: letmein

      SERVICE_TAGS: prod
      SERVICE_NAM: mysqldb 

  networks:
  - internalnet

nodeapp:
container_name: nodeappcontainer
build: .
image: nodeapp:v1
ports:

- 3000:3000
  expose:
- 3000
  depends_on:
- mysqldb
  environment:
  DB_HOST: mysqldb
  DB_USER : 'root'
  DB_PASSWORD: 'letmein'
  DB_NAME : hotel_managment
  DB_PORT : 3306
  DB_CONNECTION_LIMIT : 10
  SERVER_PORT : 3000
  SERVICE_TAGS: prod
  SERVICE_NAME: nodeappservice
  networks:
- internalnet

networks:
internalnet:
driver: bridge

This is my project structuce: (included in the image)
This is my env file
DB_HOST = localhost 
DB_USER = root 
DB_PASSWORD = letmein 
DB_NAME = hotel_managment 
DB_PORT = 3306 
DB_CONNECTION_LIMIT = 10 
SERVER_PORT = 5000

and this is how i'm connecting to the database inside node:js
let connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: process.env.DB_HOST,
port: process.env.DB_PORT,
user: process.env.DB_USER,
password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
database: process.env.DB_NAME,

});


I'm runnig this command docker-compose up -d --build inside the nodejs directory(folder)
ANd I'm getting this error :
`> nodejs@1.0.0 start

node -r dotenv/config app.js
server is listening on port: 3000
nodejs@1.0.0 start
node -r dotenv/config app.js
server is listening on port: 3000
Error connecting to database: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.22.0.2:3306
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1606:16) {
errno: -111,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '172.22.0.2',
port: 3306,
fatal: true
}`

I tried everything and nothing worked

If you're running the node app from within Docker, then I think you just need to use the container name in your .env file:
DB_HOST=mysqlcontainer 
DB_USER=root 
DB_PASSWORD=letmein 
DB_NAME=hotel_managment 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_CONNECTION_LIMIT=10 
SERVER_PORT=5000

From within the Docker context, localhost is not referring to the mysql container.
